# Altium clearance between different layers to control crosstalk /capacitance

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I want to set a clearance rule between different layers in a multi-layer board.  In particular, I have a signal class on one internal layer that a polygon pour in another layer needs to avoid.  I would also want to make sure that traces of certain net classes don't pass too close to each other on adjacent planes.  I tried to create a clearance rule with custom queries and layer specifiers, but that doesn't seem to work unless the objects are on the same layer.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What is your layer stackup ?

Comment: I'm not in front of altium so I can't test this out, but can you define a "region" over the same area as the polygon and then make some rule like the other net has a minimum width of 17 feet in that region or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the rules window, under High Speed section, there is the parallel segment rule. This can be used to control the overlap of track on different layer but I am not sure if it works also for polygon puor region. [image: Image of Altium rules window]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the clearance rules will work that way. As far as I'm aware, it will only generate 3D clearance in the component clearance rule, and electrical clearance is only between objects on the same layer.